# Make all template foreach bind the same afterAdd and beforeRemove event functions

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, event-binding

I need a way to make all templates in Knockout bind the same event functions, something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.afterAdd = function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a wrapper to the template binding that adds those options in a `foreach` scenario. Perhaps something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myTemplate = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, value, context) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if (options && typeof options === "object" && options.foreach) {
            options.afterAdd = ko.bindingHandlers.myTemplate.afterAdd;
            options.beforeRemove = ko.bindingHandlers.myTemplate.beforeRemove;
        } 

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            template: options
        }, context);


        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
    },
    beforeRemove: function (element, data) {
        console.log("remove", element, data);

        ko.removeNode(element);
    },
    afterAdd: function (element, data) {
        console.log("add", element, data);
    }
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Xnbe2/

Comment: Is there any possible way to to keep the `template` key? how about overriding `template`?

Comment: You could save a reference to the original and use it like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Xnbe2/4/

Comment: Sounds good to me! although it breaks that don't modify objects you don't own principle, but it still looks like the only possible solution I can apply... THX!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use it with a different name: `myTemplate`